# path to fetch an image in another dir

Tags: html, image, path, directory, src

I have my images in '/src/main/webapp/images' folder and my html code is in '/src/main/webapp/app/report' folder. How to specify the path to the image mentioned in that other directory?

I have tried:

`<img src=".//src/main/webapp/images/pdf-file_128.png">`

and also:

`<img src="/src/main/webapp/images/pdf-file_128.png">`

Note I am currently in webapp/app/report directory...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should be able to specify a Relative Path, using /../ to traverse up each directory level:

```
"../../images/image01.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Below are the relative path rules that you should know :

"/" returns to the root directory and starts path there

"../" moves one directory back and starts path there

"../../" moves two directories backward and starts path there (and so on...)

You need to go two level up to include the image in images folder as below :

```
<img src="../../images/pdf-file_128.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

From your current directory, this should be the path to your image

```
../../images/your image name.png
```